# does raid 0 failure mean the disk is damaged?

Tags: hard-drive, raid-0

I recently had a RAID failure on my machine. Fortunately I had most of my data backed up so I deleted the faulty RAID configuration, created a new one and reinstalled Windows. Everything's back to normal now but I was just wondering if I can expect the same thing to happen again in the near future. Is it likely that the disk is damaged?

Comment: What did the Raid failure say?

Comment: There's a screen shot here : http://i.imgur.com/Go7YvsK.jpg

Comment: Not my screen shot, but it's pretty much the same as I had

Comment: One last question what kind of drives are you using to do the raid?

Comment: 2 1TB SATA drives

Comment: Be careful when doing RAID 0, @Shazoo. This particular array has no redundancy, so make sure you always do regular backups. As for the HDDs' health and SMART status, I'd strongly recommend you to use [their manufacturer's diagnostic tool](http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en) to monitor their state. *(Use the hyperlink, if they are WD, otherwise search for this tool on the manufacturer's official website)* It'd be even better if you create a bootable flash drive with the [DOS version](http://support.wdc.com/KnowledgeBase/answer.aspx?ID=996). Good luck. Keep us posted with the results